# how to show date picker in android app

Tags: java, android, datepicker

is it possible to make a date picker in android app as in an iPhone app.

i saw a date picker in i phone app having a Done and cancel buttons. the month , year and date are been chosen by scrolling it, how can i make such a one in my android app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) and [Date Picker tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html).

Comment: The only issue with these pieces of information is it doesn't show in the google tutorial how to get the selected date and show it on a textview or any other manner.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:id="@+id/dateDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>
<Button android:id="@+id/pickDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date Picker"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity Class

```
 public class pickerdate extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);


        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        updateDisplay();
    }
    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                            mDateSetListener,
                            mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            }
            return null;
        }
     }
```